# как принять объект с UI на API

Tags: reactjs, api, asp.net-core

мой UI это React/Redux
API - .NET Core 6, не MVC

с UI я отправляю объект:

```
const obj={id:account.id, email:email,idRoles: idRoles,password: password,isActive: isAccountActive}
const formSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(adminActions.changeAccount(obj));
    props.onSubmit(e.target.value);
};
```

```
account: {id: 1, email: "some@some.com", idRoles: [1, 3], password: "12345", isActive: true}
```

мой контроллер:

```
[HttpPut]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        [Route("change")]
        public ActionResult<AccountForAdminView> Change([FromBody] ChangeAccountForm form)
        {
            return accountService.Change(form).ToAdminView();
        }
```

когда я выполняю запрос,  ChangeAccountForm у меня пустой

что можно сделать с этим?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: 1. Непонятно, в бекенде вы используете MVC?  2. Покажите весь div, из которого передается объект.

Answer (score 0):

1. Если вы используете архитектуру ASP.NET Core MVC, то создайте, в проекте на .NET 6, класс описывающий вашу Модель из

```html
account: {id: 1, email: "some@some.com", idRoles: [1, 3], password: "12345", isActive: true}
```

2. Укажите явно в вашем UI с помощью кода на Razor, в первой строке кода ссылку на модель, добавляя перед ней знак @. Далее, ваш тип метода, название контроллера и метод в который передаются данные.

```html
<form method="put" asp-controller="Название контроллера" asp-action="Change">            
       // какая то логика
</form>
```

Вот [здесь код](https://github.com/AndyBrizhak/Rocky), для ASP.NET Core MVC на .NET 5, там же ссылка на видео. Так что можете наводить красоту на React, но если решили подружить его с .NET Core, то придется разобраться, как он работает.

Comment: я использую API, а не MVC

Comment: Я не разбираюсь в фреймворках на JS, но все же..

Comment: 1.  Ваш Запрос HttpPut,  требует Авторизации с ролью  Admin. Поэтому, непонятно как в приложении реализована Identity, и авторизован ли этот Запрос из вашего UI? 2. В коде из UI, я не вижу, где указано обращение именно к методу, который вы назвали с помощью Route,  как "change".  Вот здесь  [репозиторий](https://github.com/AndyBrizhak/Mango),  с рабочим кодом на .NET 6,  где в бекенде  WEB-API, а Аутентификация и Авторизация, как Пользователей, так и обращений микросервисам друг к другу, проходит через [Duende Identity Server](https://duendesoftware.com/products/identityserver) .